# Slicing multiline strings in a list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, multiline

I am using python 3. I have a multiline, multistring list and I want to slice it in such a way that first six characters of each string remain while the remaining are excluded. When I use the code given below, I only get very first string sliced i.e. a=[alkalak], and not the others. Can anyone please let me know where I am doing it wrong?

```
a= ['''alkalaklaklakalkaalaklakalkalaklaalkal,alkkllaklllaklllka,
    akalakalkalakhgalgh, ghoahlhoonlaholh,
     khlalkhalkhlahlakhlhlakhlahkahlhakhalh''']
for char in a:
a[a.index(char)] = char[: 6]
print (a)
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? We can't help you if we don't know which language.

Comment: I have edited it. It is python

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want as output. Do you want to split on new line or do you want to split on comma? Can you please add the expected output to your post?

Comment: Actually, I want to split each string here which ofcourse is separated by a comma. All the answers given here are leading to the splitting of line.  Also, all the answers here are considering a string consisting of only one line, but not explaining what if the all or some of the strings are multiline.

Answer (score 0):

Your list `a` only has one element in it.

```
>> a = ['''alkalaklaklakalkaalaklakalkalaklaalkal,alkkllaklllaklllka,
akalakalkalakhgalgh, ghoahlhoonlaholh,
 khlalkhalkhlahlakhlhlakhlahkahlhakhalh''']
>> len(a)
1
```

You can split the single string you have in there by newlines, or commas if that is what you wanted, like this:

```
[x[:6] for x in a[0].split("\n")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
a = [line.lstrip()[:6] for line in a[0].split('\n')]
```

```
print(a)
>> ['alkala', 'akalak', 'khlalk']
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multiline list, you do not need triple quotes (''' or """). Python is reading all the characters inside the triple quotes as a single string. Therefore for your program to work, replace

```
a= ['''alkalaklaklakalkaalaklakalkalaklaalkal,alkkllaklllaklllka,
    akalakalkalakhgalgh, ghoahlhoonlaholh,
     khlalkhalkhlahlakhlhlakhlahkahlhakhalh''']
```

with

```
a= ['alkalaklaklakalkaalaklakalkalaklaalkal','alkkllaklllaklllka',
    'akalakalkalakhgalgh', 'ghoahlhoonlaholh',
     'khlalkhalkhlahlakhlhlakhlahkahlhakhalh']
```

Thus the program will stand as

```
a= ['alkalaklaklakalkaalaklakalkalaklaalkal','alkkllaklllaklllka',
    'akalakalkalakhgalgh', 'ghoahlhoonlaholh',
     'khlalkhalkhlahlakhlhlakhlahkahlhakhalh']
for char in a:
    a[a.index(char)] = char[: 6]
print (a)
```

When I execute this, I get an output as

```
['alkala', 'alkkll', 'akalak', 'ghoahl', 'khlalk']
```

Therefore, it should work now.

Comment: Thank you Shuuvam for your reply. However, Your answer is fine if each string in the list is not  mulitline but completes in one single line. But what if it each string is quite ling e.g. consists of hundreds of characters??? So than each string separated by a comma will consist of many lines. So how can I use single quote in such case??

Answer (score 0):

You might use a pattern with an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string. Match leading spaces, and capture 6 non whitespace chars in group 1 which will be returned by [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and enable `re.MULTILINE`

```
^[^\S\r\n]*(\S{6})
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ times a whitespace char without newlines
- `(` Capture **group 1** (will be returned by re.findall)

  - `\S{6}` Match 6 non whitespace chars
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nByvQn/1) or see a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hqLg35).

For example

```
import re

a= ['''alkalaklaklakalkaalaklakalkalaklaalkal,alkkllaklllaklllka,
    akalakalkalakhgalgh, ghoahlhoonlaholh,
     khlalkhalkhlahlakhlhlakhlahkahlhakhalh''']
for s in a:
    print(re.findall(r"^[^\S\r\n]*(\S{6})", s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['alkala', 'akalak', 'khlalk']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @forth bird. However, isn't this quite a complicated route, especially for someone who is not an expert in programming. :)

Comment: @ammadaslam I have added an explanation of the regex.